# How to Comparing two drawables in android

Tags: android

How can I get the drawable imgageID of  Images  on the ImageButtons to compare????? I think  i have a problem in the If{loop} thar i comare klikk1 with klikk2. here is meg code.
Any one can help with that please? i think i have problem with test method.

```
int turnone;
int turntwo;
boolean turnstate = true;
ImageButton klikk1;
ImageButton klikk2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newgame);

    final int[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.dog,
            R.drawable.eagle,
            R.drawable.elefant,
            R.drawable.kanin,
            R.drawable.gurilla,
            R.drawable.lion,
            R.drawable.dog,
            R.drawable.eagle,
            R.drawable.elefant,
            R.drawable.kanin,
            R.drawable.gurilla,
            R.drawable.lion,

    };
    int[] buttonIDs = {
            R.id.btn_1,
            R.id.btn_2,
            R.id.btn_3,
            R.id.btn_4,
            R.id.btn_5,
            R.id.btn_6,
            R.id.btn_7,
            R.id.btn_8,
            R.id.btn_9,
            R.id.btn_10,
            R.id.btn_11,
            R.id.btn_12
    };

    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> printedImagesIDs = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<ImageButton> buttons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();

    //fyller buttons
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIDs.length; i++){
        ImageButton temp = (ImageButton) findViewById(buttonIDs[i]);
        buttons.add(temp);
    }

    //populerer buttons med images
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        int random = r.nextInt(buttons.size());
        while(printedImagesIDs.contains(random))
            random = r.nextInt(buttons.size());

        buttons.get(i).setImageResource(imageIDs[random]);
        printedImagesIDs.add(random);
    }

    final ArrayList<ImageButton> final_buttons = buttons;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            flipImages(final_buttons);
        }
    }, 2000);

}

public void flipImages(ArrayList<ImageButton> buttons){
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++){
        Drawable temp = buttons.get(i).getDrawable();
        temp.setAlpha(0); //0-255, 0 = gjennomsiktig, 255 = fullt synlig
    }
}

public void test(View view){
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(view.getId());
    Drawable draw = btn.getDrawable();
    draw.setAlpha(255);
    if(turnstate){
        turnone = btn.getId();
        klikk1 =btn;
        turnstate = false;
    }
    else {
        turntwo= btn.getId();
        klikk2 =btn;

        /*mRememberPwd.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
        (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_checked).getConstantState())*/

       if(klikk1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(klikk2.getDrawable().getConstantState())){//found pair
           turnstate = true;
        }
        else {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Drawable draw1 = klikk1.getDrawable();
                    Drawable draw2 = klikk2.getDrawable();
                    draw1.setAlpha(0);
                    draw2.setAlpha(0);
                }
            }, 2000);

        }
        turnstate = true;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You did not post all of your code. What did you try that is failing?

Comment: this all the class.  you can come down on code screen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution to this would be to set a **[tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))** to the ImageView whenever you are setting the drawable and then later checking the tag set to the ImageView.

Something like this :

When you are setting drawable1 to the imageView1, do `imageView1.setTag("drawable1")`

When you want to check the drawable in imageView1, you can simply go `imageView1.getTag()`

```
 //populerer buttons med images
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        int random = r.nextInt(buttons.size());
        while(printedImagesIDs.contains(random))
            random = r.nextInt(buttons.size());

        buttons.get(i).setImageResource(imageIDs[random]);
        buttons.get(i).setTag("" +imageIDs[random]); //set the tag while setting the drawable
        printedImagesIDs.add(random);
    }



    if(((String)klikk1.getTag()).equals((String)klikk2.getTag())){//get and match the tags
           turnstate = true;
        }
```

Comment: thanks man. but this not work with String because i get a error. the message says "requerid boolean" and when i using boolean  turnstate is still false

Comment: Of course! if() needs a boolean value. I might have missed an opening brace. Try this `if(((String)klikk1.getTag()).equals((String)klikk2.getTag())){//get and match the tags`

Comment: Sir its still false in if. i can say litle bit about what i wanna do. it is a memory game that i making. i have 12 imagebuttons and 12 picture(6 + 6 ) that i put dem int[] upp in code.  a have a random methode for print out those 12 pictures on 12 buttons. when i starting the game the user can see all the picture in 2 second and after alle picture comming to be hidden that mean the user can not see them. User should klick on the first button and second button too. if the the button have same picture that mean user is found first par. if they are differen the pictuer comming be hiden again.

Comment: but when i compare the picture on first imagebutton and second one if they are the same still turnstate is false.

Comment: Try to print the tag when you are setting it and print it again when you are checking it. See if there is any discrepancy.

Comment: its working man . the problem was from other place . the         buttons.get(i).setTag("" +imageIDs[random]);  that u send me was like comment i dont know why hhah.  But thanke u for helping man . you are very helpfull person.

Comment: i open a account in here yesterday. hwo is  dowenvote your answer?

Comment: I wish I knew. Anyway, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on the left hand side of my answer. That shows that the solution worked for you. :)

Comment: Hi Swayam i hope u are good. i hade other problem. when i wana print out highest score i get a wrong score. i adding the scores in  <Long>array list. the score is a minum tmie the user using for fine all the picture.   when i printing the highest score its printing allways the last one. here is my code i my drop box, do u have time just watch to it?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/njbyujpxq27t25y/S198596Mappe3.zip?dl=0

Comment: @1987akam : I am sorry, but I don't think I have the time to go through your code right now. Can you post another question with the specific problem and I will try to help?